# Remove only font tags in a string

Tags: php, html

I only want to remove  tags in my string. But font tags are like

```
<font face="arial">
<font face="Georgia">
<font face="Tahoma">
```

...

I used this one but it does not work.

```
preg_replace('~<font[^>]*\sface="([0-9a-fA-F]{6})"[^>]*>~', '$1', $string);
```

Comment: what do you want as output for `<font face="arial">Text</font>` ?
`arial` or `Text` ?

Answer (score 3):

just use `strip_tags` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: nope, take a look at the documentation you have a second argument to save what you need

Comment: sure it will remove all tags except the tags you want to leave, but I don't think he want to write in all tags.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is matching only font names that are exactly 6 characters in length and composed of only digits and the letters A through F (upper or lower case). Try this:

```
preg_replace('~<font[^>]*\sface="([^"]*)"[^>]*>~', '$1', $string);
```

I'm assuming that the way this removes the font tag, but preserves the font name is what you intended.